# Moving code to willDisplayCell to improve UITableview scrolling

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have seen this paragraph below from the internet and followed his recommendation and moved my code to willDisplayCell. However, I don't see any performance improvement. So I did some further investigation and found out that there are some other people saying what the paragraph said is not true. [Proper Use of CellForRowAtIndexPath and WillDisplayCell](https://tech.zalando.de/blog/proper-use-of-cellforrowatindexpath-and-willdisplaycell/) . I am confused which guide I should follow at this stage as most of the time I put my code in cellForRowAtIndexPath

> But very important thing is still there: tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method, which should be implemented in the dataSource of UITableView, called for each cell and should work fast. So you must return reused cell instance as quickly as possible.
>   Don’t perform data binding at this point, because there’s no cell on screen yet. For this you can use tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: method which can be implemented in the delegate of UITableView. The method called exactly before showing cell in UITableView’s bounds.

Comment: That quoted paragraph makes no sense. Both `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `willDisplayCell` are called once per displayed cell. It makes no difference (performance wise) which method is used to update the cell's contents.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have done some test myself as well and found that there is no significant difference between putting the code in willDisplayCell and CellForRowAtIndexPath. So I believe the argument in the ink you have provided is more true. Unless anyone found anything different?